# Checking for a pattern using regex in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm attempting to use reg ex in jQuery to test whether or not a variable contains a specific pattern, if it does I'm attempting to trim the string. Here's is some pseudo code that details what I need.

```
     var $test = 12345_4
     if ($test contains '_[0-100]'){
       remove '_' && [0-100]
       // $test would equal 12345
     }
     else {
      //do something
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this using jQuery? Thanks

Comment: jQuery is helpful for things related to the DOM. Do not seek jQuery solutions for other things as it's irrelevant.

Comment: @plalx jQuery has useful things outside of DOM as well. AJAX, iterators etc

Comment: @alex Why would you use jQuery to iterate over an non-dom nodes array? Use native array functions. As for AJAX it was true for a while, but now that fetch/Request/Promise are getting supported it will become obsolete.

Comment: @plalx In 2009 it was a great idea. You're right it is less useful as browsers are filling in those gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace`:

```js
var $test = '12345_4'
$test = $test.replace(/_(\d{1,2}|100)\b/g, '')

console.log($test)
// 12345
```

- `_(\d{1,2}|100)` will match underscore followed by any number between `0` and `100`
- If match fails your input remains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as simple as this:

```
/[0-9]+(\_[0-9])/
```

Test it:

https://regex101.com/r/eT9nS3/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways, using javascript match or replace:
here are the examples:

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```

Result: Visit W3Schools!

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var res = str.match(/ain/g);
```

Result: ain,ain,ain

Sources:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

here are some regular expression cheat sheets, you can use as @marcho have mentioned:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml